How to use posterior predictions from one model (standard curve) as an outcome variable in another model?
I'm working with a dataset concerning the concentration of a large number of different chemical compounds in a mixture, using a Bayesian approach (with brms in R). The instrument that measures the compounds records a peak with some specific height, where the peak height is correlated to concentration. Each compound has a different (and unknown) concentration~peak height relationship, so we use standards (known concentrations) to try to derive this relationship for downstream estimation of concentrations. So then in a given experimental treatment, I could read the measured peak height and extrapolate the concentration of that compound. Then, in a second model I want to use the experimental independent variables as predictors of compound concentration. Because there is some significant uncertainty associated with predicting compound concentration, I want to represent this accurately in the second model.
So to give an example of how my code looks for the standard curve for a single compound:
#dummy standard data
standards = tibble(concentration = c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1),
                   peak = c(1,6, 12, 16, 25))

mod = brm(data = standards,
          family = lognormal(link = "identity"),
          concentration ~ peak,
          prior = c(prior(normal(0, 1), class = "Intercept"),
                    prior(normal(0, 0.5), class = "b"),
                    prior(exponential(0.5), class = "sigma")),
          iter = 2000, warmup = 1000, chains = 4, cores = 4)

Then, with this model, I know I can plug in new data with posterior_predict() and generate a posterior prediction for the concentration of the chemical. This is essentially giving us measurement error, but it's not necessarily a parametric distribution. So how do I use this prediction in the second model? I'd like to be able to do this within each compound using another continuous predictor (i.e pH), and also across compounds. I'm envisioning something like this for a single compound:
#simplified dummy data for a single compound
experiment = tibble(pH = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9),
                    peak = c(2, 4, 6, 9 , 15))

mod2 = brm(data = experiment,
           family = lognormal(link = "identity"),
           ***posterior_predict(mod, experiment$peak) ~ pH,
           prior = c(prior(normal(0, 1), class = "Intercept"),
                     prior(normal(0, 0.5), class = "b"),
                     prior(exponential(0.5), class = "sigma")),
           iter = 2000, warmup = 1000, chains = 4, cores = 4)

Across compounds, each compound would have a different compound-specific model informing it's posterior prediction distribution from on new data, so I'm also not sure how to specify that.  But eventually I'd like to set up a model similar to mod2 above that can compare among different compounds, where the concentration (dependent variable) comes from the posterior predictions in the first standard curve model, and I can use properties of the compounds (like molecular weight) as an independent variable. Can I just use posterior draws from posterior_predict() as data in the new model? Or is there a better way to specify all of this as a single multi-level model?

Instead of posterior draws, I would use simple summary statistics of the posterior, if the posterior is simple. For example, assuming the posterior is almost gaussian, I'd take the mean and standard deviation. Just think of it as a imperfect measure of the concentration. If the posterior is more complex, can you perhaps fit a simpler approximation like a mixture of gaussians to it?

By simple, do you mean unimodal? My posteriors are generally coming out as positive, right-skewed distributions, so maybe approximately log-normal. So I'd just estimate an approximate log-normal distribution based on mean and sd from the posterior prediction and use that for the outcome?

Yeah that sounds about right. I'd rather summarize the posterior with a single value instead of a million samples.

Ok, follow up - if I'm simulating posterior predictions my understanding is that I'm sampling the posterior distribution of combinations of slopes/intercepts/sigmas and then predicting values. If those values are outcomes in another model, maybe it wouldn't make sense to pool them into a single distribution? i.e. if a set of observations is produced in the posterior prediction from a parameter set with higher intercept then all predicted values should be higher. Then estimates of effect of another predictor on values might be less accurate?

Well, it depends if all these distributions are similar or wildly different (I'm being qualitative, I know...). If the posterior samples form a big blob of similar values, then summarizing that blob with something like its center is ok (plus some information about the shape of the blob)
